# Kernel 5.3 failes to compile: No rules to make target zImage

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, yocto, imx6

Anyone knows what is the problem of no rule to make target zImage compiling with with the Kernel 5.3?

Comment: Can you be more specific on your environment? Which Yocto version, which kernel provider, ... ? Also, can you post the entire error log ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no [arm64 zImage target](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/efi-stub.html#the-efi-boot-stub). This was a kernel design decision. Try adding

```
KERNEL_IMAGETYPE = "Image"
```

to your bitbake kernel recipe.